# How do the Unity private awake update and start methods work?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, unity-game-engine

How does Unity call the Awake, Update, and Start methods behind the scene?  That they have no access modifier to me indicates they are private methods, and they don't use anything like new or override, so how does the Unity framework find the methods to call them?

On a related question, is there any particular reason virtual methods were not used?

Edit:  For those unfamiliar with Unity scripts, this is how they generally appear:

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour{
   void Start(){
   }

   void Awake(){
   }

   void Update(){
   }
}
```

What I don't understand is how the framework finds and automatically calls those methods for each script when, by all appearances, they look to just be private methods

Comment: @DavidTorry You will probably have a better chance of getting an answer if you show some sample code so that non unity users can help you out as well?

Comment: @CKing edited to give a base example of what a script starts out like

Comment: Most likely, reflection. You'd have to ask the Unity3d authors or decompile their own code to know for sure though.

Comment: @DavidTorrey These methods have been indicated to be "Messages" in the unity doc. You could lookup what "Messages" mean in unity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a piece of information in a [Unity blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/12/23/1k-update-calls/)

> **HOW UPDATE IS CALLED**
>
> No, Unity doesn’t use System.Reflection to find a magic method every time it needs to call one.
>
> Instead, the first time a MonoBehaviour of a given type is accessed the underlying script is inspected through scripting runtime (either Mono or IL2CPP) whether it has any magic methods defined and this information is cached. If a MonoBehaviour has a specific method it is added to a proper list, for example if a script has Update method defined it is added to a list of scripts which need to be updated every frame.
>
> During the game Unity just iterates through these lists and executes methods from it — that simple. Also, this is why it doesn’t matter if your Update method is public or private.

Comment: Is there an advantage to this over using virtual methods?

Comment: @DavidTorrey it seems to me, the answer is not comprehensive and it didn't address the question properly.?

Comment: @DavidTorrey Virtual methods have overhead due to having to search within the VMT for a class and any ancestors it has, and then an indirect function call. We eliminate that by calling the Update / Start / Awake / etc. method directly. This leads to a significant perf benefit in many common scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the methods are not virtual is for performance. If it were virtual then every single MonoBehaviour would need all of the relevant methods called (Start, Awake, Update, FixedUpdate, etc.) which is a Bad Thing.