# How can I create opt-in method inheritance in C#?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, inheritance, interface

I want to create a code structure in C# that lets me inherit a class or interface, but lets you "Opt-In" for methods in inheriting classes.

A perfect example of what I want is how Unity's MonoBehaviour works. You only write code for what you need and it is simple - no need to write methods from the base class that you will just leave empty.

Example of using Unity:

```
public class MyUpdater : MonoBehaviour
{
  int num = 0;

  void Update()
  {
    num++;
  }
}
```

MonoBehaviour class also contains other opt-in methods (Start, OnDestroy, exc.) but the compiler won't care.

Obviously Unity has a heck of a lot going on inside MonoBehaviour, and I'm not looking to recreate it. (In fact I'm working within unity)

I like the code structure, and I also work as a freelancer with people who might not be as good with coding. Not needing to use overrides or exc makes it easier to understand and extend what I've created.

Thanks for taking the time to read! :)

---

**EDIT:**

For some clarification, I am by no means new to Unity or coding, however I am self-taught. I mostly work with creating backend systems.

As someone suggested below, I am asking about how to replicate Unity's "Magic" methods for classes that do not extend from MonoBehaviour.

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding your question, but I think you are simply talking about *inheritance*. You don't have to implement inherited members unless you want to (that is why it is called an *override*). You only need to implement them if you're writing to an *interface*, not a base class.

Comment: @JohnWu, my guess is that the OP doesn't realize you can make a base based on MonoBehavior  - a typical gotchya for anyone new to Unity!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer 3, if for some reason you're interested in the mechanism whereby Unity's "magic" functions work in Unity (in the current version - it changes a lot)

be sure to google the vast discussion on this, example:

[How do the Unity private awake update and start methods work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325033/how-do-the-unity-private-awake-update-and-start-methods-work)

It is very uninteresting and does not affect anything.

You may like this similar lengthy QA which gets to the heart of that issue:

[In Unity, how does Unity magically call all "Interfaces"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251078/in-unity-how-does-unity-magically-call-all-interfaces)

---

It's likely **you're just looking for** the `New` and `Override` keywords in c#.

(Every language has slightly different syntax / paradigms for inheritance.)

`Override` **extends** the function in the base class, and `New` **hides** it. The choice is yours  :)

It is widely explained, example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords

(If you are asking literally about the unusual paradigm of Unity's "magic" functions (`Update()` etc), it is not possible to do that, and you don't want to anyways.)

---

There's another possible thing you're asking:

It's quite common for new Unity devs to not realize this:

As you say Unity gives you `MonoBehavior`.

New Unity programmers often don't realize you typically **make a "base" class using** `MonoBehavior`

```
 class Weapon: MonoBehavior {
    ... explosions
    ... sound effects
    ... etc
 }
```

and then you, and the other programmers, write classes based on that class:

```
class Slingshot: Weapon {
class Peashooter: Weapon {
class SplatRoller: Weapon {
```

**Note that those new classes are indeed MonoBehaviors - you can, do and should use "Awake", "Update" etc normally in them!**

I think that may be what you're asking.

Comment: Using the 'new' keyword on methods is interesting. Not sure what the use case is for that. I've only used it on variables, most notable 'GameObject.name'.

I am aware about inheriting MonoBehaviour, then further inheriting that. I am indeed asking about Unity's "Magic" methods. 
IIRC Unity is actually C++ under the hood? I guess they are doing trickery with that.
I'm a self-taught systems programmer and I've always been curious about how they did that particular code structure.

Comment: hi @StephanEnnen.  While I (and others) am absolutely happy to help (have a look at all my answers on here) this site is really only for single, very specific questions.  If you want to ask "how do Unity's magic functions work" then **ask that**.  (in fact ... it's already been asked many times, you can spend many enjoyable hours reading about it on here.)

Comment: (2) if you don't understand / not familiar with the basics of c#, using New, Override, you'll want to familiarize yourself with that, enjoy

Comment: I guess I just didn't figure out the right terminology to use when conducting my own research on the subject.

Comment: Steve, notice the "lengthy" second link I edited in, it will have a lot of relevant information for you!  Cheers new user!  @StephanEnnen